# Oracle APEX 18 - Classic Report error Buffer to Small

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex 18, I created a Classic Report to display data from a view which has about 150 columns. If I reduce qty of columns it works but if I leave all columns it errors.

report error:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

I guess the question is: How to increase buffer to run this report?

Sample:[image]

Comment: There is still a hard limit of 32767 bytes for a row in a Classic Report. But showing that many columns doesn't seem very useful. How is the report being used?

Comment: the report was in Excel and I am automating the process, I created a Pivot View and I am using the result to display on Apex, it is a fix report, fixed column, only rows increases everyday.

Comment: You may need to put a "config" screen in the mix. The report could default to the most popular columns but allow users to add or remove columns using the config screen. Would that work?

Comment: it is a fixed columns report. I will try an page the results to display 20 columns at a time. allowing users to navigate to left or right. let see if I can manage that.

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed columns report"? I think you just described the same thing I was describing, only rather than a configuration screen, you're considering some kind of columns navigation. Something else you could consider is using `substr` to limit the output of columns with a lot of text in the query. Though if you do that you'll likely want to provide a means to get at the full text when needed.

Comment: I can't remove or hide, add or define columns. I am thinking to create in 3 reports with 80 columns each, 001 to 080, 081 to 160 and 161 to 240.

Comment: Just trying to get a better understanding... Why can't you remove or hide, add or define columns?

Comment: Business team - If I can't provide the same format they have in excel then they gonna keep in excel.

Comment: I just spoke with a member of the APEX team who suggested you try using a read-only Interactive Grid instead of an Interactive Report. Could you please try that and let me know how it works out?

Comment: Great news - It works. I created the Interactive Report and it is display the data from view.  Many thanks for your support.

Comment: That's great news! I'll put this as an answer for folks that get this error in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic Reports still have a hard limit of 32767 bytes for a row. Interactive Grids, however, do not. Create a read-only Interactive Grid instead of a Classic Report as a workaround for this issue.